# ubuntu 16.04 update nvidia no Xserver working (startx, startkde)

Tags: nvidia, 16.04

I recently updated my ubuntu 16.04 and as of today I cannot startx at all !
In the afternoon it said "low graphics mode", but as I tried to follow solutions given on forums, now I cannot start at all my Xserver.

I have nvidia-cuurent installed
I have Optimus (1 Intel card and 1 Nvidia)
I have bumbledee

please help me fix this, I can't use linux any longer (ok I have the command line but I can't do my work at all, I need the GUI).

Many thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Graphics issues after installing Ubuntu 16.04 with NVIDIA graphics](http://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-installing-ubuntu-16-04-with-nvidia-graphics)

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the version 340 of the nvidia driver `sudo apt-get install nvidia-340`, that worked for me